# What does the Japanese word "Shalaku" mean?

Tags: english-to-japanese, business-japanese

I bought this pencil from Uniball which is a Japanese made. It is a beautiful product. The name of the pencil is Shalaku. I wish to know what it means.[image]

Answer (score 5):

Shalaku is just (part of) a product name. In Japanese, it's シャ楽. Here's the [official site](https://www.mpuni.co.jp/products/mechanical_pencils/sharp_pen/very_raku/sharaku/m5_100.html) of a successor product. Etymologically, this product name is probably a parody of [Sharaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharaku), an ukiyo-e designer, whose kanji (写楽) literally means "drawing/picture" (写) and "enjoyment/ease" (楽).

Comment: It may be too obvious for folks on this site but also note that _mechanical pencil_ is called シャープペンシル or シャーペン in Japan.